# How can I retrieve data from Parse?

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, data-retrieval

How can I retrieve data from Parse.com even if I don't know the ObjectId or I have a lot of ObjectId's 
PS: I saved the data into Parse, but now the time to retrieve it into listView or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use queries for data retrieving. See https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries.